# How can I make Development builds behave the same as Testing and Production?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

When developing an app I have `sencha app watch` running.  This, of course, watches for file changes and triggers a development build.  So now I can exercise the app under development in the browser.  Nice.

The problem is a `sencha app build testing` does not behave the same way as the Development build.  The difference is in needing `requires`.  If a `requires` is missing in Development, the app functions as if it was there.

Chrome throws a warning - sometimes:

```
[W] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'MyApp.view.Etc'; consider adding Ext.require('MyApp.view.Etc') above Ext.onReady
```

After a Testing build (or similarly after a Production build), those warnings become errors and the app does not function.

Yes, during development time one should ensure all `requires` are added.  But if I miss one I'm in trouble - the painful "but it works on *my* machine" syndrome.

This would not be a problem if either I could tell `sencha app watch` to not be forgiving of missing `requires` or to tell `sencha app build testing` (or `production`) to do what the Development build does and infer the missing `requires`.

How can I make Development builds behave the same as Testing and Production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot tell `sencha app build production` to infer the missing requires, because Sencha only finds out that some required classes are missing AT RUNTIME, when the source code of your JS files should not be available at the path that the application would start searching. It's a runtime error, not a compiler error.

So you can only do it the other way around: you can edit the ExtJS source code. The warning is raised in `packages\core\src\class\ClassManager.js` like this:

```
Ext.log.warn("[Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading '" + name + "'; consider adding " +
                 "Ext.require('" + name + "') above Ext.onReady");
```

You could change that to

```
Ext.raise("[Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading '" + name + "'; please add " +
                 "'" + name + "' to your requires list");
```

Comment: Not surprising testing/production can't infer.  Was hoping there would be some kind of switch for `sencha app watch` rather than changing Ext JS code.